# Sorting of one list using specific strings contained in the list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have to sort my list of strings according to **the months name**:

```
my_list = ['apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december', 'dog_january']
```

I have to **sort by january, february, martch**, .....

My trial:

```
months = [m.split('_')[1] for m in my_list]

ans = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(months,my_list))]
```

But no success, how would you do it?

The expected answers is:

```
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) accept optional `key` parameter. Pass a key function that returns corresponding number to monthes.

```
>>> import calendar
>>>
>>> months = {calendar.month_name[i].lower(): i for i in range(1, 12+1)}
>>> my_list = ['apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december', 'dog_january']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: months[x.split('_')[1]])
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```

---

`months` is mapping between month names and numbers using [`calendar.month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name):

```
>>> months
{'april': 4, 'november': 11, 'june': 6, 'august': 8, 'december': 12, 'october': 10,
 'july': 7, 'march': 3, 'september':9, 'may': 5, 'january': 1, 'february': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a dictionary of months and their corresponding position in the calendar:

```
months = {'january': 1,
          'april': 4,
          'july': 7,
          'december': 12}
```

And then sort the list by looking up the month in the dictionary. First split each element of the list on the underscore (which gives a list such as `['dog', 'january']`) and then use `months.get` to look up the last element of this list in the dictionary:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: months.get(x.split('_')[-1]))
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```

**Edit**:

A lazier way if you have `dateutil` installed...

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x.split('_')[-1]))
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```

No need for a dictionary! `dateutil.parser.parse` parses the month string to a `datetime` object.

Comment: You should be too lazy to write a dictionary of every month

Comment: I like your lazier way, it's what I wanted the answer i just submitted to be like. I gave you a vote but stackoverflow doesn't want me to tell you

Comment: Thanks - I think your answer is preferable to mine as it doesn't rely on the third-party `dateutil` (+1)

Comment: But if one was working with `dateutil` one should use this so that's good to know. I was looking up to see if `strptime` can accept wildcard characters but it turns out you need `dateutil` for that

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_list = ['apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december', 'dog_january']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split('_')[1], '%B'))
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your list based on `calendar.month_name` or `calendar.month_abbr` :

```
>>> import calendar
>>> m=list(calendar.month_abbr)
>>> l=[(i,x) for x in my_list for i,j in enumerate(m) if j==x.split('_')[1][:3]]
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted(l,key= lambda x: x[0])]
['dog_january', 'apple_april', 'banana_july', 'carrot_december']
```